# How to run a Windows application when the ethernet cable is connected?

Tags: windows, automation, ethernet

We have a laptop that is primarily used offline, but when it is connected to our network (via ethernet cable), we would like to start a backup application. Is it possible?

The network address is static.

Comment: I don't know and haven't checked, but I think that's definitely possible. Your best bet is probably to look at the task planner. Control panel -> administration tools (approximate translation from French) -> task planner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a [scheduled task to run a program](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/). In the options there is an option to only start the task if a specific network connection is available.

In the taskoptions, select a trigger and set it to this event data (Event 10000):

[image]

[image]

In the action tab, select the program you want to run.

Answer (score 2):

Unplug, then re-plug your network cable.  Open the Event Viewer, and see if and what event is generated.  From there you can attach a task to that event, and the next time it happens your task should fire off.

This is assuming Windows Vista or higher.

Answer (score 0):

*Operating under the assumption that when it connects to the network, it also has internet access (though it may work with any network connection, not sure):*

Take a look at [wait4net.bat](http://paulhoule.com/wait4net/index.php).

It is a pretty simple batch file that is executed with:

```
wait4net.bat start "explorer.exe"
```

(where `explorer.exe` can be whatever you want to be run when a connection is established).

So you could set that up as a startup script that points to your backup software (or batch file/whatever).

Just tested on Win8x64 and it is still relevant.