# How to run a Windows application when the laptop power cable disconnected or AC power Failure

Tags: windows-7, laptop, powershell, power-supply, power-management

We have a laptop that online for 24/7

in-case of power failure need to run a batch file or program

like below
[How to run a Windows application when the ethernet cable is connected?](https://superuser.com/questions/583320/how-to-run-a-windows-application-when-the-ethernet-cable-is-connected?newreg=20cb82a150d3486399a4953ffed689da)

Comment: I don't have a laptop at the moment but I think a Windows event is generated when it switches to battery, and you can use the "Attach a task to this event" function in the Event Viewer.  Not sure which event, try experimenting.

Comment: I'd try `powercfg /batteryreport` or [Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Battery](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/win32_battery/) can't test myself.

Comment: On StackOverflow, the answer would have been [`RegisterPowerSettingNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373196(v=vs.85).aspx) but that's assuming you have a program waiting in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via [WMI](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/16/monitor-and-respond-to-windows-power-events-with-powershell/)

To do this, you create a WMI event customer with  `New-WmiEventConsumer`, of  `-ConsumerType CommandLine` so you can pass a `-CommandLineTemplate`.

The event itself would be a WMI filter, created with `New-WmiEventFilter`  and `-Query "select * from Win32_PowerManagementEvent where EventType = 4`" (4 = suspend).

Then tie customer and event with `New-WmiFilterToConsumerBinding`.

Note that the problem with suspend on power failure is that you may not have much warning.